# How can I change the language of JBoss error messages?

Tags: eclipse, jboss

It seems like a rather simple question that should be easily answerable by Google, but surprisingly I could not find the necessary information.

Currently, JBoss error messages are displayed in German in my Eclipse Console. I would like them to be in the original English to be better able to google for them.

How can I do that?

We are using JBoss Enterprise Application Server 6 and Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1.

Answer (score 10):

Adding `-Duser.language=en` to the VM arguments does the trick:

In Eclipse:

"Window - Preferences - Java - Installed JREs"

Choose a JRE

"Edit..."

Default VM Arguments: `-Duser.language=en`

Comment: I want to add that since he is launching jboss in eclipse, means he is probably using jboss Tools. And with Jboss tools open the Server tab (where you start the server) - double click the server - click launch configuration - add -Duser.language=en to the VM arguments.